# UIControl Not Calling Event Handlers If UITextFields In SuperViews Are Active Responders

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

**UIButton**

I have a View Controller in which the user needs to enter in mission level data. The view controller then has a custom UIView (Crew View) in its view hierarchy where there is a button that the user can press to add Persons to the mission. Those persons are custom UIViews as well (Person Views) that get added as children to the Crew View.

The layout looks something like this:

```
VC
|_ScrollView
  |EntryFields 
  |_ Crew View (UIView subclass)
     |UIButton
     |_ Person View (UIView subclass)
        |EntryFields
        |UIButton
     |_ Person View
        |EntryFields
        |UIButton
      ...
```

When there is no first responder for the keyboard, all the buttons pressed trigger their respective handlers regardless of where they are in their View Hierarchy.

Now if an entry field in the PersonView is active I'm able to use both the UIButton in the PersonView as well as the UIButton higher up in the Crew View.

But if an entry field in the top level is active, the handler for the buttons are not called.

Note: I know the buttons are receiving the touch events because their UI changes since the .highlighted state gets activated. The button handlers are set to .touchUpInside.

---

**UISwitch**

This has also been an issue in another part of my app with a UISwitch. The view hierarchy looks like this:

```
VC
|_ScrollView
  |Entry Fields
  |_Some UIView Subclass
    |UISwitch
```

When the keyboard was active in the scenario (from the Entry Fields up the view hierarchy), the UISwitch would not call it's handler (set on .valueChanged).

**My Solution:** I removed the target handler from the UISwitch and instead set a tap gesture recognizer for the whole view that would manually trigger the switch, this solution worked regardless if there was an active first responder up the view hierarchy.

---

Has anybody experienced this before? Why are the event target handlers not being called on the UIControls(yet they're still responding in the UI) when there are active first responders in their superview but gesture recognizers work just fine.

Everything is built programmatically, not that it should matter and the View Hierarchy debugger on XCode shows that the UIControls are not being blocked.

---

**More Information**

So the EntryFields is actually a custom component (to follow material design with a floating placeholder). The view hierarchy of the EntryField is as follows:

```
EntryField (UIView subclass)
  |_ StackView
     |_ UILabel
     |_ UITextField
```

Everything in this project is done programmatically with auto layout constraints. The EntryField interacts with its delegates by forwarding the protocol methods from the UITextField. I don't know if this is messing with the first responder chain in the application.

---

Here's a sample project (gutted version of the production code) that replicates it perfectly.

https://github.com/barbulescualex/55051678

Comment: I'd like to help you but I can't reproduce the issue. Can you check the sample project I created at https://github.com/francesco-puglisi/Stackoverflow55051678 and let me know how it's different from yours?

Comment: Can you share screens or code to understand?

Comment: @FrancescoPuglisi I've now added a sample project where the issue persists

Comment: @NileshRPatel I've now added a sample project where the issue persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the issue you're experiencing, so I did a little demo that should reproduce yours, even though I am not experiencing the same behaviour as you do, at least not for now.

Check it out ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkVx_Ud-xHQ)) and let's see if it's on you or not.

Now, I have the following hierarchy in my demo project:

[image]

And when I run it it looks like this:

[image]

Color legend:

- RED: VC's View (self.view)
- BLUE: ScrollView
- GREEN: Crew View

I have no issues at all as you can see in the video, what's different from yours?

LATER EDIT:

Ok, the issue is more than meets the eye, the good news is that there's no issue, this is just how iOS works and given this opportunity I am going to explain as detailed as possible what really happens.

Firstly, your question was why it works with the bottom textFields but it doesn't work with the top ones.

ANSWER:
You are messing it when you declare the **addButton** as a **let** instead of a **lazy var**, then you add as a target **self**, which in that scope is the **closure** itself and after you exit the scope, if you place a breakpoint in func **addPersonField** you should see that **sender.allTargets** has no targets. That's ok with the compiler since you can, there was a time when you couldn't do it, but now you can because target is declared as **Any?**, which means you could even set nil as a target and you'll experience the same behaviour.

Now, you might wonder why it works with self as a closure which gets deallocated after you exit the scope, or why it works just as fine with nil. The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) for **addTarget(_:action:for:)**

says that:

> If you specify nil, UIKit searches the responder chain for an object
>   that responds to the specified action message and delivers the message
>   to that object.

Which is your **PersonsView**, which doesn't get deallocated since is always on screen and has the specified **action** your func **addPersonField**. That's why it works before you start using any textfields (I know it works with the bottom ones, I'll get there).

Why it works with the bottom textFields you'll wonder, right? Well, again... you're doing the magic here without knowing, if you tap on a bottom textField that object becomesFirstResponder, now when an event occurs (like your **.touchUpInside** on the **Add Person** button) if the **firstResponder** can't handle it, UIKit sends the event to the text field’s parent UIView object, which in this case is the stackView, if the stackView can't handle it, the event is sent to the stackView's parent UIView which is exactly the **PersonsView** - which is the golden one, because it responds to the selector you specified **addPersonField(_:)**.

See the personsView below: 
[image: personsView - debug]

On the other hand, when you tap on the **TOP** textFields (those EntryFields), they are embedded by a **horizontal stackView** which is embedded by a **vertical stackView**, which is contained by the **ScrollView**. Now, if you followed me til here, you got the idea, the **Responder Chain** goes from **EntryField** -> **Horizontal StackView** -> **Vertical StackView** -> **ScrollView** -> **etc** but it doesn't look in the other stackViews that contain your **PersonsView**, where you defined the selector, that's why it doesn't work here.

See how the stacks are on the same level, embedded in the same VerticalStackView which is embedded in the ScrollView below:
[image: top stackview and bottom stackview on the same level - debug]

Even though, if you tap on a Top EntryField/TextField, and press return on the keyboard, you call `view.textField.resignFirstResponder()` which enables the Add Person button again.

Comment: Thank you for making the sample project, but you're missing the top level textfields. I've now linked a sample project using my custom components where the issue persists.

Comment: @AlexBarbulescu I've updated my answer, check it out!

Comment: Here's a demo repo for what I'm trying to explain here: https://github.com/MihaiEros/StackOverflow_-55122679

Answer (score 3):

I've checked your code and found issue in your button declaration. you need to use lazy in order to get the events.
i.e.

```
lazy var addButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Add Person", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.purple, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .highlighted)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addPersonField(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        return button
    }()
```

**output**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_u4a3anvOPuZGlJ3VtM15D6aBdXsclMm

> **self**: The self keyword refers to the current class instance, from
>   within that class instance.

```
func addTarget(_ target: Any?, 
        action: Selector, 
           for controlEvents: UIControl.Event)
```

> **Target**: the object whose action method is called.

**Why would self in the closure work and refer to my view controller if clicked on normally vs 
it not working if there's an active textfield in the superview:**

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget)

> The control does not retain the object in the target parameter.  It is
>   your responsibility to maintain a strong reference to the target
>   object while it is attached to a control.

i.e. It depends upon the current state of instance (Life Cycle) and how the iOS handle it.

When we use `let myButton: UIButton = {...}()` you're immediately assigning value to myButton variable there are chances that 'self' hasn't been initialized by the OS
.In order to make sure when we addTarget to our button object, 'self' is initialized properly we use lazy keyword

**Lazy**: Lazy initialization (also sometimes called lazy instantiation, or lazy loading) is a technique for delaying the creation of an object or some other expensive process until it’s needed. 
When programming for iOS, this is helpful to make sure you utilize only the memory you need when you need it.

With lazy we are making sure that our control will have a strong reference to current class which is going to handle the action

Comment: For the full bounty, could you quickly explain why this is?

Comment: @randomusername, i tried to explain why this happened. please check my updated answer

Comment: @SahilManchanda I'll be sure to add my targets outside of the closure from now on but can you explain why this doesn't work in relation to the active responders in superviews? Why would self in the closure work and refer to my view controller if clicked on normally vs it not working if there's an active textfield in the superview? Doesn't that UIComponent get initialized on the parent view init anyways? What's the difference?

Comment: @AlexBarbulescu, I've tried to answer your questions please check.